# Get dictionary from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have these two dictionaries:

```
objs = [{"code": 34, "reps": 0}, {"code": 59, "reps": 0}]
comments = [{"text": "a", "code": 34}, {"text": "b", "code": 59}]
```

I would like to update the `reps` count every time the comment is `a`. `objs` should become:

```
objs = [{"code": 34, "reps": 1}, {"code": 59, "reps": 0}]
```

I've tried:

```
for comment in comments:
    if comment["text"] == "a":
        obj = [d for d in objs if d['code'] == comment["code"]]
        obj["reps"] += 1
```

But I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. How can `obj` be a dictionary and not a list?

Comment: `obj` is a list because a list comprehension _creates_ a list. If you don't want a list, why are you writing a list comprehension?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to have the code as key and the reps as value, instead of searching the list of dicts every time? Is there really a point in having a list here?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code you should iterate through `obj` and update the `reps` count for each matching dictionary.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
objs = [{"code": 34, "reps": 0}, {"code": 59, "reps": 0}]
comments = [{"text": "a", "code": 34}, {"text": "b", "code": 59}]

for comment in comments:
    if comment["text"] == "a":
        for obj in objs:
            if obj["code"] == comment["code"]:
                obj["reps"] += 1
print(objs)
#[{'code': 34, 'reps': 1}, {'code': 59, 'reps': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary dictionary that will make it easier to search for object with right code. The code will look then:

```py
objs = [{"code": 34, "reps": 0}, {"code": 59, "reps": 0}]
comments = [{"text": "a", "code": 34}, {"text": "b", "code": 59}]

objs_tmp = {o["code"]: o for o in objs}

for c in comments:
    if c["text"] == "a" and c["code"] in objs_tmp:
        objs_tmp[c["code"]]["reps"] += 1

print(objs)
```

Prints:

```
[{"code": 34, "reps": 1}, {"code": 59, "reps": 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary where `code` is the key and `reps` is the value. The `get()` method can return a default value of `0`.

```
reps = dict()

comments = [{"text": "a", "code": 34}, {"text": "b", "code": 59}]

for c in comments:
    if c.get("text") == "a":
        key = c.get("code")
        reps[key] = reps.get(key, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem since obj is a list rather than a dictionary. It returns a list of dictionaries that match the criterion when you use a list comprehension to filter objects.

**Here's the corrected code:**

```
for comment in comments:
    if comment["text"] == "a":
        obj = [d for d in objs if d['code'] == comment["code"]]
        if obj:  # Check if obj is not empty
            obj[0]["reps"] += 1
```

here, first check if obj is not empty before trying to update the "reps" count to avoid potential errors when there is no matching item in objs.